# Using math symbols inside mbox

Tags: math-operators, inline

I am trying to write something like r=1m or r~1m inlined in my text. Currently i am using `$\mbox{r=1m}$`. However this gives me problems if I use `$\mbox{r \approx 1m}$`  it is not working and  `$\mbox{r}\approx\mbox{1m}$` is horrible to write and produces large gaps between r the ~ symbol and 1m. Is there a smarter way to do it ?

Comment: It kind of works, but gives me "Missing $ inserted when" when i need subscripts.

Comment: @ferahfeza If I could downvote a comment, I would, in this case. That solution is very wrong since it destroys the spacing around `\approx`.

Comment: @tohecz, I understand that don't want any spacing between the 'r' and '1m'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upright symbols in math can be produced by `\mathrm`.  These will scale in subscripts and superscripts, unlike `\mbox`.  Presumably your `1m` is "one metre".  The best way to set numbers with units is to use the `siunitx` package:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\( \mathrm{r} = \SI{1}{m} \).

\end{document}
```

This will also work with `\( \mathrm{r} \approx \SI{1}{m} \)`.

If you are using `\mathrm{r}` alot, you can define a macro instead:

```
\newcommand{\rad}{\mathrm{r}}
```

e.g. before `\begin{document}`, used as

```
\( \rad \approx \SI{1}{m} \)
```

Comment: Great! How would you expand this to ranges like r = 0..1m ?

Comment: `\SIrange{0}{1}{m}` whose output can be custmosized, see the [manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)